# Несколько auto в объявлении функции

Tags: c++, функции, синтаксис, объявление

Можно объявить функцию так, чтобы узнать возвращаемый тип по типу возвращаемого выражения:

```
auto foo();
```

Можно объявить так, чтобы написать возвращаемый тип в конце:

```
auto bar() -> int;
```

Но что означает следующий синтаксис?

```
auto baz() -> auto;
```

Comment: Мне кажется различий с первым вариантом немного) Тип выводится из возвращаемого значения

Comment: видимо это полная реализация принципа [AAA](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)

Comment: @KoVadim, мог бы и поподробнее в ответе написать.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически, синтаксис `auto baz() -> auto;` является корректным в соответствии с https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#5 и https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#3.

> **noptr-declarator** parameters-and-qualifiers **trailing-return-type**
>
> The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the decl-specifier-seq, type-specifier-seq, conversion-function-id, or **trailing-return-type**, in any context where such a declarator is valid.

Про значение написано далее в https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#3:

> If the function declarator includes a trailing-return-type ([dcl.fct]), that trailing-return-type specifies the declared return type of the function.

То есть возвращаемый тип определяется `-> auto` в нашем случае. И далее в том же пункте:

> If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from non-discarded return statements, if any, in the body of the function.

Таким образом, разница между 1 и 3 только формальная: в первом случае `declared return type` будет `placeholder type auto` до параметров, а в третьем -- `placeholder type auto` после. Но, так как это один и тот же `placeholder type auto`, то поведение у них одинаковое, а именно: `the return type of the function is deduced from non-discarded return statements, if any, in the body of the function`.

Answer (score 0):

Это комбинация 1 и 2 случаев. Эквивалентна 1 по поведению.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращаемое значение функции будет вычислено на основе типа выражения после return. Можно почитать тут https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

> The auto specifier may also be used with a function declarator that is
>   followed by a trailing return type, in which case the declared return
>   type is that trailing return type (which may again be a placeholder
>   type).